# magento #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, database, magento

we are using magento platform with MYSQL

i am runing folowing query in database :

```
INSERT INTO eav_attribute (age, ...) VALUES (1020, ....);
```

here age is attribute code and 1020 is attribute id.

but i am getting following error :

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '..) VALUES (1020, ....)' at line 1`

Comment: share complete insert query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inserting only one field then change it to

```
INSERT INTO eav_attribute(age) VALUES(1020);
```

If your column of type `VARCHAR` you need to quote your column values using single quote `'`. It should be

```
VALUES ('1020'
```

Comment: i used this : INSERT INTO eav_attribute ('age', ...) VALUES ('1020', ....);  but same error

Comment: NO, that's wrong query statement. see edit in answer again.

Comment: i am getting this : #1054 - Unknown column 'age' in 'field list'

Comment: Do you have a column names `age`? post your table structure.

Comment: Have you run the exact same query in answer. You shouldn't get any error. make sure you are running the query in correct database.

Comment: if 'age' column is not there is database, how i can add it ?

Comment: this worked for me : ALTER TABLE eav_attribute ADD age INTEGER i am trying next step now